# How to stop all actors and wait for them to terminate?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

I am implementing unit tests for my Akka project. To avoid `InvalidActorNameException`s and the like, I want all actors that were created within one unit test to be stopped before the next unit test is being run. So, for each actor created within a unit test, I call `_system.stop(someActorRef)` at the end of it. However, it takes some time for an actor to actually be stopped, and unfortunately, the next unit test usually starts running before the actors that were created within the previous one are actually gone. And since there is neither a `Future` that is being returned by the `stop` method, nor an `awaitStop` method available, I really don't know how to solve this. Currently I call `Thread.sleep(1000)` at the end of each unit test and hope all actors are dead by then, but, obviously, I cannot stay this way. :D

I'd appreciate any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this at the end of your test:

```
val probe = TestProbe()
probe.watch(someActorRef)
system.stop(someActorRef)
probe.expectMsgType[Terminated]
//another way
//probe.expectMsgPF() {
//  case Terminated(someActorRef) =>
//}
```

Comment: This looks really interesting, however, it doesn't compile:

Comment: ````missing argument list for method apply in object Terminated
[error] Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)(_,_)` instead of `apply`.
[error]     probe.expectMsg(Terminated(someActorRef))````